# Order created but Paypal has no record of payment

Tags: paypal, magento-community

We have received a number of orders which have come through to us but sitting at "Payment Pending". For each we have learned to check our PayPal account to see if the payment has processed, but not been pulled through to Magento.

Some of these payments have actually processed correctly, but the majority of these orders have no payment information in PayPal.

I can understand if a payment goes through correctly but Magento doesn't pick it up, but how can an order be created with no payment into PayPal? Also, some customers, where we have received no payment into PayPal for the order, have reported that they have had money taken from their account. I have followed this up, asking for transaction details, etc, whereupon they have not responded so I assume they were mistaken, but this is not good from a customer service standpoint.

We are using Magento Community 1.7.0.2 and default PayPal integration. (See below) Any ideas?

[image: PayPal Integration]

Comment: Are you using the provided PayPal integration, or a custom integration module?

Comment: The Magento default provided PayPal integration

Comment: Hmm. Can you add that to the question, so others know?

Comment: I'd recommend creating a support ticket with PayPal.

Comment: I need to know if it is a PayPal or Magento issue though?

Comment: I don't know, but it sounds like it could be a combination of both. Paypal will likely be able to help you figure out...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may be wrong on this, but I think Magento saves the order before going to the payment processor page.
This happens (I think) for every payment that requires leaving the shop.
So in your case I think some of the clients went to the paypal page and did not pay. They just abandoned the checkout process.
You can try to do the same.
Go through the checkout process and close the page when you get to Paypal.
Then check if the order is in the backend and if there is any trace of payment in your paypal account.

Comment: This is my thought, as any time I have asked for transaction details I haven't been provided it. But my wife (she runs our shop) believes there is something wrong with the site. I just ran a test through, it DOES create the order "Pending Payment" and no transaction is in PayPal. So it seems extremely likely that this is the case.

Comment: I have an other suggestion. You can randomly call 2 or 3 people that have a pending order but no payment to ask them to confirm that this has happened. You can also offer them a 10E coupon code or something for their collaboration.

Comment: I have done this, no response. I believe this is the cause of the issue, they just haven't completed checkout but the order has processed. I will have to create a new question to ask how to stop this occurring as I run a multi-vendor site and they are receiving order notices and dispatching without us receiving the payment. So a big issue.

Answer (score 1):

Enable (if not already) System and Exception logging.

`System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Log Settings > Enable.`

Also enable debugging in the PayPal payment method configuration area.

- https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Abstract.php#L573-L585

This will create a Paypal `.log` file in `var/log/` as well to help identify what the root cause of the issue is going forward.

IF any of the following was enabled I would review the log files, especially the `var/log/exception.log` file for any relevant PayPal exceptions or errors occurred during the transactions.

You can also set the Payment Action to Authorization instead of Sale, to not capture funds until you've got the order details properly in both to avoid disgruntled customers.

> **Authorization:** Approves the purchase, but puts a hold on the funds. The amount is not withdrawn until it is “captured” by the
>   merchant.
>
> **Sale:** The amount of the purchase is authorized and immediately withdrawn from the customer’s account

More details on setup can be found here:

- http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/payment/paypal-payment-standard-intro.html

Comment: I have implemented these functions, now just have to wait to see if it happens again.